# Remove Ubuntu 11.10 from Dual Boot Windows XP without XP CD?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu on a old Windows XP computer using Dual Boot, i have no XP Cd and desperately need to remove it! EasyBCD does not work on windows XP, iF I just delete the Ubuntu partition all hell breaks loose and i have to reinstall ubuntu to get my XP back. Please help me i am only 12 and i have made a stupid error on my mum and dads computer and will get into serious trouble if i dont fix it soon!.

Extra Information:
I use the gnu boot loader to choose my operating system, but my mum and dad need my help to open a word document, they have only just grasped double clicking! I installed it off a cd that i made, the computer is 64-bit AMD Athlon with one 160gb hard drive, 512mb ram and a Sis mirage2 128mb shared video card. Its a COMPAQ presario.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a definite fix but is a quick workaround that might give you some more time:

1. Boot into Ubuntu
2. Open a terminal (type "temrinal" in the unity dashboard or press Ctrl+Alt+Del)
3. type/copy:

   ```
   Sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
4. Find the line that says:

   ```
   set default="0"
   ```
5. Change the number to the position where your XP sits in dual boot menu, start counting at 0 - usually the first in the list will boot first hence the default="0".
6. Now find the line that says:

   ```
   set timeout=10
   ```
7. change the 10 to 0 and it should just boot straight into windows on the next boot without displaying.

When you want to boot into Ubuntu (when your parents are out and you want to fix your mess!) hold shift while its booting and it should display your grub (dual boot) menu.

Good luck!!

Comment: Is there an option in your boot menu for windows? if not open a terminal, type "sudo update-grub" - then restart to see if the windows option has come then you can try the instructions again with the correct default.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Super Grub, a livecd that fixes Grub and Windows MRB to set Windows partition as the main boot partition.

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Comment: Thank you so much, i was worried no one was going to reply, i will check it out right now

Comment: What do i do when i get to the website?